# terraform: unable to set vpc name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am starting to learn terraform. I created a vpc thusly:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "my-vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    terraform = "true"
  }
}
```

I thought it would be named `my-vpc` in the management console but it wasn't. The name is blank. And on the documentation page there is no "name" attribute: when I tried setting a `name` I got an error during the apply (An argument named "name" is not expected here.)

I can't believe you can't set a name?! What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Name of a VPC is just a tag called `Name`:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "my-vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    terraform = "true"
    Name = "myvpc"
  }
}
```